# ExtJS XTemplate and empty JSON parsing

Tags: json, templates, extjs

How do you determine that a JSON object is empty in a XTemplate? I've tried

```
<tpl if="myObject != {}">
<tpl if="myObject">
<tpl if="myObject != undefined">
```

etc, but can't seem to find the right way to detect an empty object. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<tpl if="!Ext.isEmpty(myObject)">
```

Comment: I'm using Ext 3.4 and isEmpty did not work when passing it an empty object, to make it work I had to wrap Ext.toArray around the object and test the returned array instead. e.g. var empty = Ext.isEmpty(Ext.toArray(obj));